# How to Remove Tick Marks on Boxplot

Tags: r

I am trying to remove the x-axis tick marks from my boxplot, but keep the labels associated with the tick marks. Is this possible in base R?

```
colors <-c("lightskyblue3", "gray78","gold1", "wheat1")
boxplot(avgscore~module, data=microbox,
names=c("Cultural Diversity","UDL","Differentiated", "Instruction","Classroom Management"),ylim = range(2.5,4.5), ylab="Average Score", 
# main="Distribution of Average Score by Module",#
col=(c("lightskyblue3", "gray78","gold1", "wheat1")))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

First suppress the x-axis with `xaxt = "n"` and then add `axis` with `tick = FALSE`

```
graphics.off()
b = boxplot(mpg~cyl, mtcars, names = c("four", "six", "eight"), xaxt = "n")
axis(side = 1, at = seq_along(b$names), labels = b$names, tick = FALSE)
```